# Sum of projections?!

Tags: linear-algebra

Given this basis A = $\{ (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, 0), (-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, 0), (0, 0, 1) \}$. How can I know the value of $[(1,2,3)]_{A}$ by finding $(1, 2, 3)$ as a sum of projections?

Comment: Maybe it is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ instead of $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}$ ?

Comment: Do you know how to do projections in general?

Comment: I read about it but I don't understand it that much

Comment: Nobody knows I guess

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. :) It appears you [asked the same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812339) (which was closed by community vote), then deleted it and asked again. Not sure why the other one was closed (the plurality reason was "Not mathematics", which doesn't seem true); perhaps people felt there wasn't enough evidence of effort on your part? Anyway, it's fine to ask about homework here, but it would be good to add information about what specifically you don't understand. Have you seen a formula for decomposing a vector into components in an orthonormal basis?

Comment: No I haven't... I need directions not the answer itself

Comment: Form a matrix $A$ whose columns are the basis vectors. Check if the matrix is orthogonal. If so, then $A A^T = I_3$. A vector $y$ can be written as a linear combination of the columns of $A$, i.e., $y = A x$, where $x$ is the coordinate vector. Hence, $y = A A^{-1} y$. Write $A A^{-1}$ as the sum of column-row products.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang The other one was closed (and all close votes were cast) after the edit. That should explain the close votes.

Comment: @EricaJ. I suppose you made the edit to the first post because you typo'ed, $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}$ instead of $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$? You should have just corrected that typo there, rather than editing to remove the question and re-ask.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Brak}[1]{\langle #1\rangle}\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}\newcommand{\Basis}{\Vec{e}}$Here are some general pointers:

- If $S = (\Vec{v}_{1}, \dots, \Vec{v}_{n}) = (\Vec{v}_{j})_{j=1}^{n}$ is a basis of $\Reals^{n}$, the *coordinate vector* $[\Vec{x}]_{S} = (x_{1}, \dots, x_{n})$ of $\Vec{x}$ with respect to $S$ is the ordered $n$-tuple of numbers satisfying
  $$
  \Vec{x} = x_{1} \Vec{v}_{1} + \dots + x_{n} \Vec{v}_{n}
    = \sum_{j=1}^{n} x_{j} \Vec{v}_{j}.
  $$
- If $A = (\Vec{u}_{j})_{j=1}^{n}$ is an *orthonormal* basis of $\Reals^{n}$ (each vector has length one, and any two are orthogonal), then
  $$
  \Vec{x} = \Brak{\Vec{x}, \Vec{u}_{1}}\, \Vec{u}_{1} + \dots + \Brak{\Vec{x}, \Vec{u}_{n}}\, \Vec{u}_{n}.
  $$
  That is, the components of $\Vec{x}$ with respect to $A$ are the dot products of $\Vec{x}$ with the basis elements. (The summands on the right are the orthogonal projections of $\Vec{x}$ to the lines spanned by the basis elements. It's a good exercise to see how this works for the standard basis of $\Reals^{n}$.)

Comment: @goblin: Actually, I'd prefer to denote the components $x^{j}$ (in the spirit of covariant and contravariant indices) and then write $[\Vec{x}]^{S}$ to indicate "$S$ comprising all the indices". :) Your multiplicative notation still works as a formal dot product of the coordinate vector with the basis denoted as a column having basis elements as entries:$$\Vec{x} = [\Vec{x}]^{S} \cdot S = [\Vec{x}^{j}] \cdot [\Vec{v}_{j}] = \sum_{j} x^{j}\Vec{v}_{j}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you the general idea. Say you have a vector $x = (\alpha_1, \ldots,\alpha_n)$ represented in the usual basis of $(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$, $(0, 1, 0,\ldots, 0)$, etc. and you want to know what that vector looks like in a different basis $A$ constructed from the orthonormal vectors $v_1, v_2,\ldots, v_n$. The coefficients $\alpha_i$ should actually be thought in the following way:

$$ x = \alpha_1 (1,0,\ldots, 0) + \cdots + \alpha_n (0, \ldots, 0,1). $$

The $\alpha_i$ can be computed by taking the dot product of $x$ with the $i$th basis vector. For a general basis, the following formula holds:

$$x = \sum_{l=1}^n (x\cdot v_l)\,v_l,$$

where $x\cdot v_l$ represents the dot product of $x$ and $v_l$. The coefficients $x\cdot v_l$ represent the entries of your vector in the basis $A$. In your case $v_1 = \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, 0\right)$ $v_2 = \left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1}{2}, 0\right)$ and $v_3 = (0, 0, 1)$. Computing the dot products gives you the representation of $x$ in this basis. Let me know if you have any difficulty with this.